# Python phonenumbers error str has no attribute country code

Tags: python, python-3.x, phone-number, python-phonenumber

I am trying to get the carrier of a phone number

I am using phonenumbers in python and keep getting this error

```
‘str’ object has no attribute ‘country_code’
```

Here is my code:

```py
import phonenumbers
num = input("phone number")
from phonenumbers import carrier
Carrier = carrier.name_for_number("+1" + num, "en")
print(Carrier)
```

[image]![The error message]

Comment: What is the exact error with trace?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: what `phonenumbers` is? there is no statement in your snippet consist `country_code`, you should provide full code to let others help you debugging

Comment: Granted, the [docs](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/phonenumbers.carrier.name_for_number) are hard to read, but the first argument is expected to be a "PhoneNumber object", not a string.

Comment: I suggest you [read the documentation](https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/). There is an example that shows how to correctly use `name_for_number()`.

Comment: Please post the full stack-trace _as text_.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [name_for_number](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/blob/8d068aed3647d6cf6f407f5672a936e8bb4b117a/python/phonenumbers/carrier.py#L82) wants an object, so you would have to parse the input first:

```py
num = input("phone number")
num_object = phonenumbers.parse("+1 {}".format(num))
```

I would suggest you to do something like this:

```py
import phonenumbers 
import phonenumbers.carrier 

num_object = None 

while num_object is None: 
    try: 
        num = input("phone number: ") 
        num_object = phonenumbers.parse("+1 {}".format(num), region="US") 
    except Exception as error: 
        print("ERROR: {}".format(error)) 
          
carrier = phonenumbers.carrier.name_for_number(num_object, "en") 
print(carrier)
```

Comment: When I do this after  entering the phone number it is blank

Comment: Carrier might not be available for your number, docstring indicate that an empty string is returned if no carrier is found. Check their database for more details:
https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/tree/8d068aed3647d6cf6f407f5672a936e8bb4b117a/python/phonenumbers/carrierdata

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the documentation:

For mobile numbers in some countries, you can also find out information about which carrier originally owned a phone number.

```py
>>> from phonenumbers import carrier
>>> ro_number = phonenumbers.parse("+40721234567", "RO")
>>> carrier.name_for_number(ro_number, "en")
'Vodafone'
```

---

The name_for_number gets a PhoneNumber object as a parameter, not a String (str).